# How to handle Redis session when db disconnects

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, redis

I am having issues with losing my Redis connection that I use for sessions in my Express App:

```
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
sessionStore = new RedisStore(config.db.redis.connection);
sessionStore.client.on('error', function(err){
  console.log("Redis error " + err);
});

app.use(express.session({
  secret: config.secret,
  maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
  store: sessionStore
}));
```

When it goes down so does the site due to sessions no longer being available.  I am thinking of doing a fallback to memoryStore or a secondary db but would like to use that fallback just until I can reconnect again (I am not overly concerned too much with sessions being lost - just don't want the site to go boom).

How can I do this? An existing plugin would be grand but have not found anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried working with replication Master-slave option? If master goes down switch to slave and when master is up point back to master.

Your application should check master connection, if it is down it should fetch data from slave and resume the service.

You can have slave running on same server or anywhere else.

Comment: That sounds nice in theory but I am not finding any code examples on how to deal with that in a session fail on Express. I can catch the fact that sessions are down or Redis threw up but from there...

Answer (score -3):

Redis has a reputation as one of the most reliable data stores available. Rather than trying to engineer a fallover solution, I would suggest fixing your Redis. Or, use a hosted service like [Redistogo](http://redistogo.com/) at $7 a month, which should have nearly zero downtime.

Comment: This is hosted Redis (IrisCouch) - regular downtime - RedisTogo used to be an option in NodeJitsu but they dropped them because of some issues. So rather than keep my fingers cross and continue dealing with this I'd rather patch it up

Comment: You're going to have to write a good bit of code to fall back to a different cookie store, and if you use MemoryStore, you'll get constant logouts as a user bounces between different servers. Why can't you connect to Redistogo directly, even if Nodejitsu doesn't directly support them?

Comment: Well I can connect to them but the truth is that these services do go down and right not the user experience is just a 500 error. I have patched things up to show a maintenance page and I will look at another service.

Comment: Just remember that your fallback code can fail too. If you are more confident in your database being available, you could switch to https://github.com/jebas/connect-pg